# Android intent.Action_view file permission denied

Tags: android, file, android-intent, view, action

I am trying to get a media file from my storage and play it by the action_view intent. It's saved in the cache. My code looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();
        viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(prefs.getAssetDir() + "/" + poi.getRoute().getId() + "/"
                + poiMedia.getContentMedia().getMedia().getFileName());
        Log.w("Karl",file.exists()+" < File exists"); 
        // returns true
        viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
        viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(viewMediaIntent);
    }
};
```

The error I get is the Permission Denied Error. I already got the user-permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest.

Can someone help me please?

Edit:

Logcat:

```
Failed to open file '/data/data/nl.kloeg.beleefroutes/cache/beleefRoutes/com.burokloeg.beleefroutes.0210OpPadMetRembrandt1/38669.mp4'. (Permission denied)
E/AwesomePlayer(1931): cannot create dataSource
W/AwesomePlayer(1931): onPrepareAsyncEvent() finishSetDataSource_l error(-2147483648)
W/AwesomePlayer(1931): abortPrepare() mIsAsyncPrepare (1), err (-2147483648)
```

Comment: post the logctat message

Comment: added the logcat message.

Comment: Can you post the full logcat? I meant the entire exception report, not literally everything.

Comment: It's all what I get...

Comment: E/MediaPlayer(22900): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(22900): Error (1,-2147483648)

Answer (score 3):

This may be late but I encountered the same thing.
The way I solved it by adding

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use FileProvider
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider 
and check this StackOverFlow answer for a sample code: [FileProvider is very confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685461/fileprovider-is-very-confusing)