# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _data

Tags: android

```
fun convertUriToPath(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): String {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        try {
            val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null)
            val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
```

this is my code i am trying to fetch VCf File path from content URI i have when i try to use this function to  get  File path then i am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _data

in the line

```
cursor =context.getContentResolver
```

How to fix this?

Comment: above method is deprecated, you need to use [Fileproviders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) please follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685461/fileprovider-is-very-confusing/49685978#49685978)

Comment: ok wait @MohammedFarhan let me check i am struggling in this

Comment: @MohammedFarhan  i have content URI from that uri i am get file path

Comment: `FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider that facilitates secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a content:// Uri for a file instead of a file:/// Uri.` definition says everything

Comment: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard/181i3d1d71400ef8b807.532i5b9514cb8c7e0135.3789r121699-4B2953392D4D59432D  i am getting this URI  now from this URI i have to get file path @MohammedFarhan please help me in this