# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65637, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-image, android-gallery, android-photos

I have a gallery photo selection tool but every time I select it, my program gets error. I have not been able to correct the error, I have tried many different different things, but I did not work. I'm waiting for help.

Below is the function I use to select photos from the gallery.

```
private void openPickImageIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Bir Görsel Seçin"), PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

And this is my onResult function.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null)
            return;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        String token = SatekApplication.getInstance().getLoginResponseDto().getToken();
        File file = new File(filePath);

        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.create(reqFile);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), photoFileName + ".jpg");//todo test

        Call<ResponseBody> req = service.uploadImage(token, asset.getUploadUrl(), reqFile);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ShowLoadingDialogEvent());
        photoUploadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonUploadImage.setEnabled(false);
        imageViewTick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        req.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new HideLoadingDialogEvent());
                createAsset();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new HideLoadingDialogEvent());
                photoUploadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonUploadImage.setEnabled(true);
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error I received:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.satisekibim.android, PID: 7241
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65637, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:61 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.satisekibim.android/com.satisekibim.android.products.product.addproduct.AddProductActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:282)
                  at com.satisekibim.android.products.product.addproduct.AddProductFragment.onActivityResult(AddProductFragment.java:518)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:156)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: this crash is happening because `filepath` is null and the method you are using to get filepath from `Cursor` is `deprecated`.  Please follow this answer which demonstrate usage of [FileProviders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685461/fileprovider-is-very-confusing/49685978#49685978)

Comment: This does not solve my problem because I want access to the gallery, not the camera.